# Custom filepath on server parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm working with parse.com for my server end. I'm wondering if there's a way for files to be saved into subfolders. For example my file is currently saved with a url like this:

> http://files.parsetfss.com/bb2767e6-fc18-4ff5-a071-199803c9aac2/tfss-d056e28e-1e02-49dd-930b-e46790a2e38d-Drums.png

is there a way I can get it to look like this instead:

> http://files.parsetfss.com/bb2767e6-fc18-4ff5-a071-199803c9aac2/tfss-d056e28e-1e02-49dd-930b-e46790a2e38d/Drums.png

and for the same extension (tfss-d056e28e-1e02-49dd-930b-e46790a2e38d) apply to each row?

The reason I need this is because I'm actually uploading html files and it can't find its assets if they get renamed...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Cloud Hosting documentation here:

https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide

Basically whatever files/folders you put in the "public" folder will be publicly available.

You can use it to upload files you want to be shared normally, instead of the way you described in your question which is for files you want to attach to objects.

Comment: Hi I looked into this however it is limited to 500 files so it's not really a viable solution for me. My other option is to get back the filepath of the new file and edit all the files to the new filepath but it's going to be a little tedious… Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need to consider alternative solutions if you want to host more than 500 files but don't want to deal with the unique naming that parse gives them.

Comment: Yeh I'll try change the filepaths if it's too tedious I'll look into alternatives. Thanks for the advice!